# Array.prototype.sort() fails when input items has more than 2 digits

Tags: javascript, sorting

I am training some javascript and i have seen a case in which i cant sort an object type array.
By the way if input array has only 1 digit items naive sort() function works as expected.

input is like --> [10,6,6,10,10,9,8,8,3,3,8,2,1,5,1,9,5,2,7,4,7,7]

when i run

var arr = Object.values(input).sort();

input becomes --> [1, 1, 10, 10, 10, 2, 2, 3, 3,  4,  5,  5, 6, 6,7, 7,  7,  8,  8, 8, 9,9]

where i miss the points, i am open to your ideas.

Thanks.

Comment: Value shoulb me made as integer first, It may be treated as string in your case. Let me know how you got this array values

Answer (score -2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

> The sort() method sorts the elements of an array in place and returns the sorted array. The default sort order is ascending, **built upon converting the elements into strings, then comparing their sequences of UTF-16 code units values**.

```
const input = [10,6,6,10,10,9,8,8,3,3,8,2,1,5,1,9,5,2,7,4,7,7]
// use a compareFunction: (a, b) => a - b
var arr = input.sort((a, b) => a - b)
```

More about the `compareFunction`, `a` and `b` are elements of the array. To decided if `a` is to be sorted before `b`, `sort` function uses the result of the `compareFunction`.

If the result of the `compareFunction`,

- is -ve, `a` is placed before `b`
- is 0, relative position of `a` and `b` will not be changed
- is +ve, `a` is placed after `b`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, this is really what i was looking for.